# Powershell Copying Files Script

Tags: powershell, scripting

I am trying to copy, and rename multiple files to miltiple folders. The folders will be labeled sequentially like the files. For example I need to copy Reports.txt change the name to Reports_NW01_20120219.txt to a folder called NW01 then the same process for NW02-NW18. The folder and file names increase by 1. I am new to powershell so please spare me. I have pasted what I have below. I am attempting to read in the date and then append it to the file name. I am at a complete loss now. So any help is appreciated:

```
$date = read-host "Enter date of the report YYYYMMDD"
write-host $date  

for ($Counter = 1; $Counter -le 1; $Counter++) 
{     

    #Destination for files 
    $DropDirectory = "C:\Users\dh0520\Documents\Powershell Staging\"  
    #Current Location of the files
    $file = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\dh0520\Documents\Powershell Test\NW01\Reports.txt" 

    if ($Counter  -lt 10) {

        $Destination = $DropDirectory+'NW0' + $Counter  
        $file = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\dh0520\Documents\Powershell Test\NW0" + $Counter + "\Reports.txt" 
        Copy-Item $file.FullName ($Destination + $file.BaseName + "_NW0" + $Counter + "_" + $date +".txt")

    }

    If ($Counter -ge 10) { 

        $Destination = $DropDirectory+'NW' + $Counter 
        $file = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\dh0520\Documents\Powershell Test\NW" + $Counter + "\Reports.txt" 
        Copy-Item $file.FullName ($Destination + $file.BaseName + "_NW" + $Counter + "_" + $date +".txt")

    }   

}
```

Comment: What's the error message/problem?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are getting errors with the get-childItem.  It is because you cant build the path like that.  Try it this way:

```
$file = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\test\NW0$($Counter)\Reports.txt"
```

and this way:

```
$file = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\test\NW$($Counter)\Reports.txt"
```